# All dynamically created buttons react to same click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I create my buttons using ngFor to iterate through my names array. I would like to pass my button (e.g. button1) to my function in typescript to change the color of the clicked object. However, I am struggling with this und would appreciate any help.

```
   <ion-list *ngFor="let name of names; let i = index; ">
        <ion-card>
        <div>
          <div>
              <button #button1 ion-button block class="studentbutton {{ studentbutton1 }}" style="background-color:#058D65" (click)="studentbuttonOneClicked(i, button1);"></button>
              <button class="studentbutton  {{ studentbutton2 }}" style="background-color:#7ED321" (click)="studentbuttonTwoClicked(i)"></button>
              <button class="studentbutton {{ studentbutton3 }}" style="background-color:#FFCD56" (click)="studentbuttonThreeClicked(i)"></button>
              <button class="studentbutton {{ studentbutton4 }}" style="background-color:#FF6384" (click)="studentbuttonFourClicked(i)"></button>
              <ion-input placeholder = "contr." id="contribution"></ion-input>
          </div>
        </div>
            </ion-card>
      </ion-list>
```

This is the function in my typescript file

```
studentbuttonOneClicked(i, button1) : void {
    console.log("start"); 
    var eld = document.querySelector('button1'); 
    console.log(eld);
    console.log(button1); 
    let el: HTMLElement = button1; 
    var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( button1 ) );
    myEl.addClass('highlighted');
  }
```

I would like to specifically change the passed object, because it would otherwise modify the color of all buttons of that row.

Comment: You want to just change color of button which is clicked ? or you have to perform any other functionality on it ?

Comment: @RohanKadu for now I am trying to simply change the color of the clicked button within the typescript function. Later on I will pass a value to a certain variable if a specific button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to make it highlighted then you can change your CSS class :

Declare one variable *isStudentSelected* in component with value say -1.

```
<button *ngFor="let student of students; let i = index" (click)="setSelectedRow(i)" [class.studentHighlighted]="i == isStudentSelected"></button>
```

And add your highlighted code in CSS with class name

```
  //CSS code
 .studentHighlighted{

 background-color:#058D65

}

//Angular Component Code
public isStudentSelected(selectedIndex:int){
  this.selectedStudent = selectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I click one button, I would like to highlight this one button and the previously highlighted button should return back to "normal". Is this also possible?

Comment: Yes it will only apply that class which was clicked as you will be updating the variable with index number of that button .

Comment: Oh great. I was trying your approach, but seem not to get it right. Could you eventually show how you declare your isStudentSelected variable and change the value inside the method?

Comment: I have updated answer . Please check and Approve if it helped !!

Comment: I have tried your new code but ran into errors. I have created a plunkr which might be easier for you to understand my code. https://plnkr.co/edit/XKxzoNbaxSrPO6Gf4aYd?p=preview Thanks a lot for your time